# How to parallelize a banded direct solver?

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, parallel-computing, banded-matrix

I have a linear system whose matrix that is diagonally dominant, non-symmetric, but banded.   Since the band-radius is 2 (producing only 5 variables per equation), a banded direct solver (gaussian elimination without pivoting) should be fairly fast to produce a solution.  I was just wondering if there is a way to parallelize a banded gaussian elimination?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From what I have seen from [your other question](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/866/how-to-reorder-variables-to-produce-a-banded-matrix-of-minimum-bandwidth), your half-bandwidth is not actually two, as one of your diagonals is roughly $\sqrt{n}$ entries away from the main diagonal.

With that said, even if you really did have an $O(1)$ bandwidth, I would have pointed you to the general literature on parallel sparse-direct solvers, as $O(1)$ bandwidth can be thought of as a special case where the separators for nested-dissection can be trivially found.

In particular, I recommend chapter 4 of Anshul Gupta's dissertation, [Analysis and Design of Scalable Parallel Algorithms for Scientific Computing](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.46.2932). I found that chapter, along with [Liu's review paper](http://www.jstor.org/pss/2132786), sufficient to implement a scalable sparse-direct $LDL^T$ factorization without pivoting. I would start with those papers before looking into adding pivoting.

All of the machinery for the general sparse-direct case essentially reduces to the cyclic reduction algorithm that Heath discusses in @Allan P. Engsig-Karup's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Cyclic reduction algorithm should be feasible. See for example http://www.cse.illinois.edu/courses/cs554/notes/09_tridiagonal_8up.pdf.