# Memory and time requirements of the scipy sparse spsolve

Tags: linear-solver, sparse-matrix, scipy

I have a system of fairly large set of linear equations (approximately 30K equations). I am using `scipy.sparse.spsolve` to solve these equations.  Initially, I tried with 10K equations, but my program got killed due to memory issue. In general, I would like to know the memory and time requirements of the `spsolve` algorithm and exactly how the algorithm solves the system of equations. Is it based on factorization? Anyone can help me?

NB* - system of equations does not have a predefined structure like symmetricity etc, only thing is it is very sparse.

Comment: I have solved systems with ~ 10M systems of equations in a laptop with 8 GB of RAM.

Comment: @nicoguaro using numpy/scipy ?  I am very much surprised. I find it difficult to run mine with 10K equations on a server with 32GB RAM. You care to give some tips ?

Comment: My matrices come from finite elements and I use COOrdinate list (COO) for the assembly and turn it into  Compressed Sparse Row (CSR) for the solution phase.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you need to make sure that you construct & store your original matrix already in a sparse format. Otherwise, your problems can start already at this stage, since storing such a large matrix in dense format and only then converting it to sparse can easily blow up the memory.

According to [scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve.html) documentation, by default it uses [UMFPACK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UMFPACK), which would be multifrontal LU factorization. [This answer](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/8972/20688) will give you some insight on what may actually happen in your case (fill-ins). In short, there is a chance that even though your non-factorized matrix is sparse, its structure (and reorderings used in the factorization algorithm) result in a lot of fill-ins, resulting in a much denser factorized matrix.

In general, it's quite hard to give time&memory estimates for sparse matrix factorization since a lot depends on the structure of the matrix, used algorithms, and [strategies to reduce fill-ins](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/sparse-matrix-reordering.html).